# Deleting entries in one collection that are linked to other in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections: albums and images.....

```js
db.albums.findOne().pretty()
{
    "_id" : 67,
    "images" : [
        52901,
        57320,
        96342,
        99705
    ]
}
```

And for images:

```js
db.images.findOne().pretty()
{ 
    "_id" : 99705, 
    "height" : 480, 
    "width" : 640,
    "tags" : [ "dogs", "kittens", "work" ]
}
```

Every images are supposed to be in an album.The image id is present in the albums collection as shown in the example. But there are some images with no album. I want to delete those images alone. can anyone help me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) to calculate all `distinct` `images` from `albums` collection like this :

```
var allDistinctImagesFromAlbums = db.albums.distinct("images")
```

so `allDistinctImagesFromAlbums` contains array list of all `images` like 
`[52901, 57320, 96342, 99705]`

Now use above variable to `images` collection which `_id` `$nin` above array like this :

```
db.images.remove({"_id":{"$nin":allDistinctImagesFromAlbums}})
```

above query remove all those images documents which not referred in `albums` collection.